# TLS Version specific cipher suites

Tags: tls, cryptography, cipher-selection, ciphers

I have come across that GCM, CCM, SHA-256 and SHA-384 Cipher suites are TLS 1.2 only. So TLS handshake can not be performed with lower TLS version using these suites.

1. I am trying to figure out supported cipher suites per protocol version (SSL v3, TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2) from this list
   http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4
2. Are Cipher suites mentioned in TLS 1.1 RFC (https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4346.txt) supported by TLS 1.0 and SSL v3?
3. Similarly suites mentioned TLS 1.0 supported by SSL v3 and vice versa?

Comment: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/ciphers.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.) See openssl output below and [excellent Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) below

2.) No not all of them, see the tables at the [URL below](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).

3.) No not all of them, see the tables at the [URL below](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

```
openssl ciphers -v 'ALL:!aNULL'    
    ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
    ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
    ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
    ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
    ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
    ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
    SRP-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
    SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
    SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=SRP  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
    DH-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
    DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
    DH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
    DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
    DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
    DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
    DH-RSA-AES256-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
    DH-DSS-AES256-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
    DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
    DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
    DH-RSA-AES256-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
    DH-DSS-AES256-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
    DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
    DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
    DH-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
    DH-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
    ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
    ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
    ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
    ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
    ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
    ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
    AES256-GCM-SHA384       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
    AES256-SHA256           TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
    AES256-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
    CAMELLIA256-SHA         SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
    PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
    ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
    ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
    ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
    ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
    ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
    ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
    SRP-DSS-AES-128-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=DSS  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
    SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
    SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=SRP  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
    DH-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
    DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
    DH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
    DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
    DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
    DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
    DH-RSA-AES128-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
    DH-DSS-AES128-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
    DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
    DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
    DH-RSA-AES128-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
    DH-DSS-AES128-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
    DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=SEED(128) Mac=SHA1
    DHE-DSS-SEED-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=SEED(128) Mac=SHA1
    DH-RSA-SEED-SHA         SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=SEED(128) Mac=SHA1
    DH-DSS-SEED-SHA         SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=SEED(128) Mac=SHA1
    DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
    DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
    DH-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
    DH-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
    ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
    ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
    ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
    ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
    ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
    ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
    AES128-GCM-SHA256       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
    AES128-SHA256           TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
    AES128-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
    SEED-SHA                SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=SEED(128) Mac=SHA1
    CAMELLIA128-SHA         SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
    IDEA-CBC-SHA            SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=IDEA(128) Mac=SHA1
    IDEA-CBC-MD5            SSLv2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=IDEA(128) Mac=MD5 
    RC2-CBC-MD5             SSLv2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=RC2(128)  Mac=MD5 
    PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
    ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
    ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
    ECDH-RSA-RC4-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
    ECDH-ECDSA-RC4-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
    RC4-SHA                 SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
    RC4-MD5                 SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=MD5 
    RC4-MD5                 SSLv2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=MD5 
    PSK-RC4-SHA             SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
    ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
    ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
    SRP-DSS-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=DSS  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
    SRP-RSA-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
    SRP-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=SRP  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
    EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
    EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
    DH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
    DH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
    ECDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
    ECDH-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
    DES-CBC3-SHA            SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
    DES-CBC3-MD5            SSLv2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=MD5 
    PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
    EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=DES(56)   Mac=SHA1
    EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=DES(56)   Mac=SHA1
    DH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=DES(56)   Mac=SHA1
    DH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=DES(56)   Mac=SHA1
    DES-CBC-SHA             SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=DES(56)   Mac=SHA1
    DES-CBC-MD5             SSLv2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=DES(56)   Mac=MD5 
    EXP-EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH(512)  Au=RSA  Enc=DES(40)   Mac=SHA1 export
    EXP-EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH(512)  Au=DSS  Enc=DES(40)   Mac=SHA1 export
    EXP-DES-CBC-SHA         SSLv3 Kx=RSA(512) Au=RSA  Enc=DES(40)   Mac=SHA1 export
    EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5         SSLv3 Kx=RSA(512) Au=RSA  Enc=RC2(40)   Mac=MD5  export
    EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5         SSLv2 Kx=RSA(512) Au=RSA  Enc=RC2(40)   Mac=MD5  export
    EXP-RC4-MD5             SSLv3 Kx=RSA(512) Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(40)   Mac=MD5  export
    EXP-RC4-MD5             SSLv2 Kx=RSA(512) Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(40)   Mac=MD5  export
```

Comment: Thanks. This section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Algorithm solves my question.

Answer (score 7):

As an addon to Trey's answer:

- I use the string `ALL:COMPLEMENTOFALL` when want I every cipher suite.
- I use the `-V` (upper case V) option to make OpenSSL output the hex-IDs of the cipher suites.

Note: OpenSSL is not authoritative for answering these questions. IANA is. (But I couldn't get their CSV file parsed nicely.)

```
$ ./openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0-pre6-dev  xx XXX xxxx

$ ./openssl ciphers -V 'ALL:COMPLEMENTOFALL' | awk '{print $4}' | sort | uniq -c
     64 SSLv3
     24 TLSv1
     70 TLSv1.2
```

And there is a breakdown by protocol version below.

## SSLv3

```
$ ./openssl ciphers -V 'ALL:COMPLEMENTOFALL' | sort | grep ' SSLv3 '
0x00,0x01 - NULL-MD5                SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=MD5
0x00,0x02 - NULL-SHA                SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x07 - IDEA-CBC-SHA            SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=IDEA(128) Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x0A - DES-CBC3-SHA            SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x13 - DHE-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x16 - DHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x1B - ADH-DES-CBC3-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x2C - PSK-NULL-SHA            SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x2D - DHE-PSK-NULL-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x2E - RSA-PSK-NULL-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x2F - AES128-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x32 - DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x33 - DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x34 - ADH-AES128-SHA          SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x35 - AES256-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x38 - DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x39 - DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x3A - ADH-AES256-SHA          SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x41 - CAMELLIA128-SHA         SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x44 - DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x45 - DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x46 - ADH-CAMELLIA128-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x84 - CAMELLIA256-SHA         SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x87 - DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x88 - DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x89 - ADH-CAMELLIA256-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x8B - PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x8C - PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x8D - PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x8F - DHE-PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x90 - DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x91 - DHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x93 - RSA-PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x94 - RSA-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x95 - RSA-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x96 - SEED-SHA                SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=SEED(128) Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x99 - DHE-DSS-SEED-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=SEED(128) Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x9A - DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=SEED(128) Mac=SHA1
0x00,0x9B - ADH-SEED-SHA            SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=SEED(128) Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x06 - ECDHE-ECDSA-NULL-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x08 - ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x09 - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x0A - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x10 - ECDHE-RSA-NULL-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x12 - ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x13 - ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x14 - ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x15 - AECDH-NULL-SHA          SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=None Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x17 - AECDH-DES-CBC3-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=None Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x18 - AECDH-AES128-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=None Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x19 - AECDH-AES256-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=None Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x1A - SRP-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=SRP  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x1B - SRP-RSA-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x1C - SRP-DSS-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=DSS  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x1D - SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=SRP  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x1E - SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x1F - SRP-DSS-AES-128-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=DSS  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x20 - SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=SRP  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x21 - SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x22 - SRP-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x34 - ECDHE-PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x35 - ECDHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x36 - ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
0xC0,0x39 - ECDHE-PSK-NULL-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
```

## TLSv1

```
$ ./openssl ciphers -V 'ALL:COMPLEMENTOFALL' | sort | grep ' TLSv1 '
0x00,0xAE - PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256   TLSv1 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
0x00,0xAF - PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384   TLSv1 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
0x00,0xB0 - PSK-NULL-SHA256         TLSv1 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA256
0x00,0xB1 - PSK-NULL-SHA384         TLSv1 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA384
0x00,0xB2 - DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256 TLSv1 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
0x00,0xB3 - DHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384 TLSv1 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
0x00,0xB4 - DHE-PSK-NULL-SHA256     TLSv1 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA256
0x00,0xB5 - DHE-PSK-NULL-SHA384     TLSv1 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA384
0x00,0xB6 - RSA-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256 TLSv1 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
0x00,0xB7 - RSA-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384 TLSv1 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
0x00,0xB8 - RSA-PSK-NULL-SHA256     TLSv1 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA256
0x00,0xB9 - RSA-PSK-NULL-SHA384     TLSv1 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA384
0xC0,0x37 - ECDHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256 TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
0xC0,0x38 - ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384 TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
0xC0,0x3A - ECDHE-PSK-NULL-SHA256   TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA256
0xC0,0x3B - ECDHE-PSK-NULL-SHA384   TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA384
0xC0,0x94 - PSK-CAMELLIA128-SHA256  TLSv1 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA256
0xC0,0x95 - PSK-CAMELLIA256-SHA384  TLSv1 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA384
0xC0,0x96 - DHE-PSK-CAMELLIA128-SHA256 TLSv1 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA256
0xC0,0x97 - DHE-PSK-CAMELLIA256-SHA384 TLSv1 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA384
0xC0,0x98 - RSA-PSK-CAMELLIA128-SHA256 TLSv1 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA256
0xC0,0x99 - RSA-PSK-CAMELLIA256-SHA384 TLSv1 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA384
0xC0,0x9A - ECDHE-PSK-CAMELLIA128-SHA256 TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA256
0xC0,0x9B - ECDHE-PSK-CAMELLIA256-SHA384 TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA384
```

## TLS1.2

```
$ ./openssl ciphers -V 'ALL:COMPLEMENTOFALL' | sort | grep ' TLSv1.2 '
0x00,0x3B - NULL-SHA256             TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA256
0x00,0x3C - AES128-SHA256           TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
0x00,0x3D - AES256-SHA256           TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
0x00,0x40 - DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
0x00,0x67 - DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
0x00,0x6A - DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
0x00,0x6B - DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
0x00,0x6C - ADH-AES128-SHA256       TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
0x00,0x6D - ADH-AES256-SHA256       TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
0x00,0x9C - AES128-GCM-SHA256       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
0x00,0x9D - AES256-GCM-SHA384       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
0x00,0x9E - DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
0x00,0x9F - DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
0x00,0xA2 - DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
0x00,0xA3 - DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
0x00,0xA6 - ADH-AES128-GCM-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
0x00,0xA7 - ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
0x00,0xA8 - PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
0x00,0xA9 - PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384   TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
0x00,0xAA - DHE-PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
0x00,0xAB - DHE-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
0x00,0xAC - RSA-PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
0x00,0xAD - RSA-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
0x00,0xBA - CAMELLIA128-SHA256      TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA256
0x00,0xBD - DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA256
0x00,0xBE - DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA256
0x00,0xBF - ADH-CAMELLIA128-SHA256  TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA256
0x00,0xC0 - CAMELLIA256-SHA256      TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA256
0x00,0xC3 - DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA256
0x00,0xC4 - DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA256
0x00,0xC5 - ADH-CAMELLIA256-SHA256  TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA256
0xC0,0x23 - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
0xC0,0x24 - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
0xC0,0x27 - ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
0xC0,0x28 - ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
0xC0,0x2B - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0x2C - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0x2F - ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0x30 - ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0x72 - ECDHE-ECDSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA256
0xC0,0x73 - ECDHE-ECDSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA384
0xC0,0x76 - ECDHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA256
0xC0,0x77 - ECDHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA384
0xC0,0x9C - AES128-CCM              TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESCCM(128) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0x9D - AES256-CCM              TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESCCM(256) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0x9E - DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM      TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESCCM(128) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0x9F - DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM      TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESCCM(256) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0xA0 - AES128-CCM8             TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESCCM8(128) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0xA1 - AES256-CCM8             TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESCCM8(256) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0xA2 - DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM8     TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESCCM8(128) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0xA3 - DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM8     TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESCCM8(256) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0xA4 - PSK-AES128-CCM          TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM(128) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0xA5 - PSK-AES256-CCM          TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM(256) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0xA6 - DHE-PSK-AES128-CCM      TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM(128) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0xA7 - DHE-PSK-AES256-CCM      TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM(256) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0xA8 - PSK-AES128-CCM8         TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM8(128) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0xA9 - PSK-AES256-CCM8         TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM8(256) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0xAA - DHE-PSK-AES128-CCM8     TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM8(128) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0xAB - DHE-PSK-AES256-CCM8     TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM8(256) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0xAC - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESCCM(128) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0xAD - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESCCM(256) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0xAE - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM8 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESCCM8(128) Mac=AEAD
0xC0,0xAF - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM8 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESCCM8(256) Mac=AEAD
0xCC,0xA8 - ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
0xCC,0xA9 - ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
0xCC,0xAA - DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
0xCC,0xAB - PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305   TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
0xCC,0xAC - ECDHE-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
0xCC,0xAD - DHE-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
0xCC,0xAE - RSA-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
```

## Couldn't get IANA-file to parse.

This here was my initial attempt to break this down by version. Not good to read.

This is a breakdown by the column in the CSV-file that points to the defining document. Unfortunately they do not align nicely with the individual protocol versions. (Manually annotated by me after the # hash mark.) Also: TLSv1.0 (RFC2246) is not even listed.

```
$ lynx --dump https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters-4.csv | sed 's_^[^[][^[]*\[_\[_p' -n | sort | uniq -c
      1 [Pasi Eronen, <pasi.eronen&nokia.com>, 2008-04-04.  2008-04-04]"
      4 [Pasi_Eronen]
     10 [RFC2712]
      4 [RFC2712][RFC6347]
      6 [RFC4162]
      9 [RFC4279]
      3 [RFC4279][RFC6347]
      7 [RFC4346]   # <- TLS 1.1
      2 [RFC4346][RFC6347]
     20 [RFC4492]
      5 [RFC4492][RFC6347]
      3 [RFC4785]
      9 [RFC5054]
     36 [RFC5246]   # <- TLS 1.2
      3 [RFC5246][RFC6347]
     12 [RFC5288]
     16 [RFC5289]
      7 [RFC5469]
     18 [RFC5487]
      8 [RFC5489]
      1 [RFC5489][RFC6347]
      1 [RFC5746]
     24 [RFC5932]
     54 [RFC6209]
     42 [RFC6367]
     16 [RFC6655]
      4 [RFC7251]
      1 [RFC7507]
      7 [RFC7905]
```

Comment: Great info StackzOfZtuff. Thanks for adding that to the post. +hat tip